# AngularJS Promise - error while navigating away from page if data still loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-services

I have an Angular service that uses $q to create a promise to return to the Angular controller layer. Inside that service it makes an async $http.get request for data.

When a user changes to another area of our intranet they are reloading a new page. That navigation action causes the promise to fail (if you don't wait for the data to async load)
The promise failing in our app shows a custom error message dialog.

What is the best way to handle this? Is this a known issue? We don't want users to see an error message as they navigate off the page. Is this because under the covers XMLHttpRequests get cancelled when navigating away from a page?

controller code:

```
    $scope.showEmployees = function() {
        employeeService.getEmployees().then(function(data) {
            $scope.employees = data;
        }, function(errorMessage) {
            alertMessage(errorMessage);
        });
    };
```

service code:

```
        getEmployees: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get("/api/employees").success(function(data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function() {
                deferred.reject("An error occurred while retrieving data.");
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

Comment: Maybe set a global during an onbeforeunload handler, and if the global is set, you don't display error messages?  Alternatively, the function you pass to .error() takes a parameter that you're not using.  You could look at this to distinguish requests canceled because of navigation from real failures.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use onbeforeunload event like this:

```
var isUnload;

function getEmployees() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get("/api/employees").success(function(data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }).error(function() {
        if (!isUnload) {
            deferred.reject("An error occurred while retrieving data.");
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() {
    isUnload = true;
});
```

Comment: Thanks this might be a good work around. It looks like there might be some missing documentation on the AngularJS site. Looks like there is a $browser.defer.cancel(deferedId) but what I really want is $browser.defer.cancelAll();

Comment: @BuddyJoe did using $browser.defer.cancel(deferedId) or $browser.defer.cancelAll(); work for you?

I am facing a similar problem, and want to resolve it.